# What must I do to get past the "Store listings" part of the Microsoft Store app submission process?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

When I try to submit my app to the Microsoft Store, the "Store listings" section will not change from the "Not started" status, seemingly no matter what I do:

[image]

I've clicked all the links in that section and done what I could, but nothing satisfies the logic behind recognizing this part of the process as even being started, let alone completed.

Comment: Text description and at least one screenshot are required for the step to be completed, are you sure you added both?

Comment: I did not see any opportunity at that point to add any text or screenshot. All it is is to add or remove languages (I stayed with the default English only), export listings (which I did), and import listings, which I did not do, because I didn't know what to import.

Comment: That is strange, did you click on `English (Unitest States)`? It should allow you to edit your store listing after you click on the language.

Comment: @DipenShah: If you make your last suggestion an answer, I will accept it and award you the Bounty.

Comment: Sure I can add it as an answer as long as it worked for you!

Comment: Yes, that last suggestion (clicking on Engllish) worked; maybe I neglected to try it earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on language it self should open Store listing page for selected language.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy. I had clicked and filled out "English", but not "English (United States)". I expected plain "English" to work. Nothing on the UI indicates that you have to select and fill out "English (United States)" to be able to publish.